# Apache, virtual hosts, and default sender for sendmail

Tags: apache-2.2, php, unix, virtualhost, sendmail

So here's my issue...I have two sites hosted on one machine using apache's virtual hosts.  I want to send emails from the two different sites (domain.com and domain2.com) using the appropriate email addresses.  I currently have this value in php.ini:

`sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fuser@domain.com`

But when I try sending an email from a script on domain2.com it obviously is delivered with a `From: user@domain.com` header.  Apache doesn't allow you to set a rule like this from within the `<VirtualHost>` directive:

`php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fuser@domain2.com"`

So what's the best way to accomplish this?  I've tried setting `php_admin_value mail.force_extra_parameters "-fuser@domain2.com"` from within the domain2.com's `<VirtualHost>` directive but all emails are still coming from domain.com.  Any ideas?

Comment: Plase see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179014/how-to-change-envelope-from-address-using-php-mail

Comment: I saw that, but editing every mail() call wasn't a viable option for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you're not allowed to set the sendmail_path from within the `<VirtualHost>` directive, you **can** set it within the `<Directory>` directive.  So I simply have something that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Standard stuff goes here

    <Directory /dir/to/your/web/root>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fuser@domain2.com"
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure if it's the most proper or elegant way to accomplish this, but it definitely worked.  Sorry it took so long to respond, I don't go on SF that frequently and forgot about this question.

Comment: Jeff, I couldn't up your response but **THANK YOU**! I've been fighting this for three days now with no success and your response is the first one that actually gets my e-mails to send! Elegant or not, a send is better than not!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `-fuser@domain.com` from your php.ini. And then modify the [mail](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function for each script that sends mail for each host appropriately. That way you can pass the correct -f argument for each virtual host.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that in my OP.  I did remove the `-fuser@domain.com` from the php.ini file prior to adding the `mail.force_extra_parameters` to the vhost's conf file. That still wasn't working.  I found a way that worked for me that I'll be posting later tonight

Comment: Please post it for another user seems to be having [the same problem](http://serverfault.com/questions/340734/setting-the-from-address-apache-php-sendmail)

Comment: Yes, this info would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Whoops sorry for the delayed answer.  I completely forgot about this question because I don't come over to SF too frequently

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing problem when i tryed to modify my sendmail_path using php_value or ini_set/ini_get (even with safe_mode off! i don't really know why - PHP 5.3.3).
However i re-read the php [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mail.php), and it's the solution was on the function.

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

So last parameter allow additional parameters.
I changed my php mail code from
mail($to,$subject,$message,implode("\r\n", $headerFields), **"-f".$from**);

I think that's [Jeff](https://serverfault.com/users/83539/jeff) you'll find this smarter.

Hope this help.